# Python overloading variable assignment

Tags: python, operator-overloading, magic-function

I have a class definition like

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.content = u''
        self.checksum = hashlib.md5(self.content.encode('utf-8'))
```

Now when I change the **self.content**, I want that **self.checksum** would automatically calculated. Something from my imagination would be

```
ob = A()
ob.content = 'Hello world' # self.checksum = '3df39ed933434ddf'
ob.content = 'Stackoverflow' # self.checksum = '1458iabd4883838c'
```

Is there any magic functions for that? Or is there any event driven approach? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: look into python [`property`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property)

Answer (score 10):

Use a Python [@property](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property)

**Example:**

```
import hashlib

class A(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._content = u''

    @property
    def content(self):
        return self._content

    @content.setter
    def content(self, value):
        self._content = value
        self.checksum = hashlib.md5(self._content.encode('utf-8'))
```

This way when you "set the value" for `.content` (*which happens to be
a property*) your `.checksum` will be part of that "setter" function.

This is part of the Python [Data Descriptors](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html) protocol.